Юнит тесты про неткод Unity ECS
Нужно сделать некоторые тесты по неткоду в области подключения, отключения и авторизации между клиентом и сервером в Unity на ECS. Как я понимаю тесты сами должны создавать условия для из выполнения, и просто создав систему авторизации я не подключаюсь к серверу, у меня не срабатывает даже моя система авторизации из за отсутствия NetworkId, который по видимому автоматом как то создается самим юнити. Что нужно сделать для подключения к серверу и выполнению юнит тестов в Unity(из теорий что нужно все системы которые за это отвечают вручную создать, потом всех их запустить и вот уже потом можно что то свое тестировать).
